# Intel Core i7 processor and cache behaviour

Tags: c, performance, caching, assembly, intel

I have run the following assembly code: (that iterates 1000 times through an array of 10 000 000 elements each of 4 bytes) on an Intel Core i7 CPU (with 32KB L1 data cache and 64B L1 cache line size)

```
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov edx, 1000
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4]
    add eax, 1

    cmp eax, 10000000
    jl  .L3
    sub edx, 1
    je  .L4
.L2:
    mov eax, 0
    jmp .L3
.L4:
    mov eax, 0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Perf gives the following stats:

```
10,135,716,950      L1-dcache-loads
601,544,266      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    5.93% of all L1-dcache hits
4.747253821 seconds time elapsed
```

This makes totally sense because I am accessing 1 000 * 10 000 000 = 10 000 000 000 elements in memory, and the cache line being 64B (with an element in vector of 4 B) this means an L1 cache miss at every 16 elements (therefore about 625 000 000 L1 cache misses).

Now, I have "unrolled" a part of the loop and the code is:

```
    .cfi_startproc
    mov     edx, 1000
    jmp     .L2
.L3:
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 4]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 8]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 12]

    add     eax, 4

    cmp     eax, 2500000
    jl      .L3
    sub     edx, 1
    je      .L4
.L2:
    mov     eax, 0
    jmp     .L3
.L4:
    mov     eax, 0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Perf how gives the following stats:

```
2,503,436,639      L1-dcache-loads
123,835,666      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    4.95% of all L1-dcache hits
0.629926637 seconds time elapsed
```

I cannot understand why?

1) There are fewer L1 cache loads, since I am accessing the same amount of data?

2) The code runs 6 times faster than the first version? I know that it has
to do with Out-of-order execution and superscalar execution, but I cannot explain this in detail (I want to understand exactly what causes this speed-up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news - you have a bug in second one ;)

Original code

```
.L3:
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4]
    add eax, 1
    cmp eax, 10000000
    jl  .L3
```

Second version

```
.L3:
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 4]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 8]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR v[0+eax*4 + 12]
    add     eax, 4
    cmp     eax, 2500000  <- here
    jl      .L3
```

In both cases you need to load 10 mln elements. Max element address accessed in both cases must be the same, right?

So in first case max address is:

```
(10.000.000-1)*4 = 39.999.996
```

and second:

```
(2.500.000-4)*4+12 = 9.999.996
```

exactly 4 times less.

Just fix second example to `cmp eax, 10000000` too.

Comment: Ok :( I have fixed it. Now the cache hits and loads are ok. But it still gets executed faster: 2.617806762 seconds. Why? It's only because it has to do fewer jump instructions?

Comment: Unrolling usually brings gains. Second thing we don't know which i7 you have. Also check what happens if you don't always load to ecx but different registers (first 3 loads are "noneffective" as last one always overwrites ecx so CPU may see that and do some magic here). Also check what happens if you unroll 8 or 16 times.